# Bash Shell Scrpiting, How can I write a script to run a program which ask for input?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a program, `porodry`, which will need read a parameters file to run, suppose the file called `test1`, so if I use bash

I can run

```
./porodry
```

terminal will show:

```
please input your parameters file name:
```

I will type

```
test1
```

then the program start to run, and will have some outputs shows on the terminal, like

```
Please input an int number:
```

then I will type something like:

```
1110
```

then the program will keep running.

I want to write a script, which will automatically read the input and output the terminal content to a `test1.terminal` file

Please help out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what the program really does. If it just reads from the standard input, you cat just pipe the input to it and redirect the output to a file:

```
echo test1 | ./porodry > test1.terminal
```

If it messes with the terminal, you might need `expect`.

Comment: Thanks, your script works, but I forgot one thing, there is not only one input, there is another input following that, please help out again. Thanks.

Comment: @user43506: Try `{ echo test1 ; echo input2 ; } | ./porodry > test1.terminal`.

Comment: Thanks, it is in use